# nodeload.js - get this : (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added.

Tags: node.js

js to drive the testing of an helloworld express.js.
There is nothing much in the sample express.js than sending back a hello world.

I started my app.js 
When I run the following command:
 `nodeload.js -c 100 -n 1000 http://xxx:`8082

I got this warnings all over the place; warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Then it completed with some statistic, however  many stack traces were dumped with the node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Completed 1000 requests

```
Server:                                 myhost :8082
HTTP Method:                            GET
Document Path:                          /
Concurrency Level:                      100
Number of requests:                     1000
Body bytes transferred:                 83989
Elapsed time (s):                       0.46
Requests per second:                    2178.65
Mean time per request (ms):             42.89
Time per request standard deviation:    21.84
```

Percentages of requests served within a certain time (ms)

```
Min: 21
Avg: 42.9
50%: 30
95%: 90
99%: 102
Max: 103
```

Is this the nodeload issue? Or the sample hello world issue?
People mentioned about `process.setMaxListeners(0)`.
But that does not resolve the issue for me when I set it in the app.js

Please advise what is this warning complaining about?
This is not a node.js issue?  How to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see one of the stack traces you mentioned? It depends on which code is mentioned in the trace.